# How can I pass data in the JVM between the agent dll and a debugger GUI executable?

Tags: c++, dll, jvm

I want to design a native agent for the JVM via the Java Virtual Machine Tool Interface for C++. I want to also design a executable for the user to see what is going on within the JVM and this will be a GUI designed in C++ Qt. I setup a solution in Visual Studio with 2 projects:

- agent project JVMTI dll
- Qt EXE GUI project

In the Qt project, I made sure to include the dll so that it can communicate between the GUI and JVM. However, I read that the DLL cannot contain shared variables so the code below doesnt work. For context, here is the agent dll source that the JVM attaches:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "../include/jvmagent.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, char* options, void* reserved)
{
    JVMAgent::agentOnLoad(vm);
    return JNI_OK;
}

__declspec(dllexport) long JVMAgent::agentOnLoad(JavaVM* vm)
{
    JVMAgent::initialized = true;
    return JNI_OK;
}
```

The corresponding header for the JVM agent:

```cpp
#pragma once

#ifndef DLLAGENT_H
#define DLLAGENT_H

#include "../src/pch.h"

namespace JVMAgent
{
#pragma data_seg("SHARED")
    inline bool initialized = false;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:SHARED,RWS")
    __declspec(dllexport) long agentOnLoad(JavaVM* vm);

}

#endif // DLLAGENT_H
```

I tried to do some shared memory workarounds but it has not been working so far. The goal is to eventually communicate all the JVM functions and data to the executable code here:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "debugvisualizer.h"
#include "jvmagent.h"

DebugVisualizer::DebugVisualizer(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(onButtonPressed()));
}

void DebugVisualizer::onButtonPressed()
{
    ui.textBrowser->setText(QVariant(JVMAgent::initialized).toString());
}
```

The code above defines a pushbutton where when I press it, the JVM contents should display. So far, I cannot seem to find a way to make the two communicate. The web is sparse with JVMTI documentation with it often being outdated or for Linux, but I need to develop on Windows. Is there a way for this to happen since I have to pass the dll as an argument into the Qt executable. If all of this still doesn't make too much sense, here is what I am trying to accomplish (which does not work yet but is the goal):

1. Start the JVM and load the agent.
2. JVM calls `Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM*, ...)` from above.
3. The agentOnLoad function will set a single boolean to true.
4. The Qt executable includes the header and reads the boolean value.
5. The Qt executable displays the updated boolean value.

Again, I know that this is not possible because dll's cannot "share" variables across processses. I just want to know if there is another way of accomplishing above. Hopefully this is detailed enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario, there are two different processes:

1. JVM with the agent library
2. GUI executable

To make them talk to each other, you need an [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (inter-process communication) mechanism.
The linked article lists all typical IPC approaches. Sockets, pipes or shared memory are the most common for a purpose like yours.

For example, that's exactly how a Java debugger in IDE works: JVM starts with a `jdwp` agent attached, and IDE debugger talks to the agent via a socket connection using [JDWP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jdwp-spec.html) protocol.